# Linking .lib of MySQL in C/C

Tags: c++, mysql, visual-studio, static, linker

So, after whole day of trial and effort, I still couldn't figure answer to this question.
I'm perfectly aware of 
[this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7976014/static-linking-of-mysql-in-c-c) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1450452/mysql-connector-c-library-linking-error-problem)
but they don't quite give answer to the question.

So, the problem is when compiling program, let's say, like this one:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
#include <mysql.h>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    MYSQL *connection, mysql;
    MYSQL_RES *result;
    MYSQL_ROW row;
    mysql_init(&mysql);
}
```

and I get linker error

```
undefined reference to `mysql_init@4'
```

I tried adding to input section libmesql.lib and mysqclient.lib, both simultaneously and separately. Tried copying .lib files to Visual Studio default folder, than attempted compiling it by setting path in Linker->General->Additional Library Directories. Tried #pragma comment as well - still to no avail.

So if anyone out there could explain what am I doing wrong (and possibly a way to solve this problem) it would be much appreciated.

p.s. And please, don't answer with links to MySQL documentation - I got them [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7976014/static-linking-of-mysql-in-c-c).

Comment: Would you mind posting the Visual Studio project file so I could take a look?

Comment: Sure, I uploaded it [here](http://www.mediafire.com/?1v99zhclz98fn43).

Answer (score 0):

Link your code with **mysqlclient.lib**.

**Properties->Linker->General->Additional Libraries**

Add the path to your library here.

Comment: Please, read more attentively. As I stated in my question, I've tried this already, but this didn't help.